# Speech recognition in a loop

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Trying to get the below code to continue running and providing me outputs until I give it a keyword.  Can't figure this out, all its doing is giving me what i've said and then when I stop speaking it prints and stops executing.

```
def get_audio():
    while True:
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            said = ""

            try:
                said = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(said)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception: " + str(e))

        return said.lower()
```

Comment: this might be a good place to use a Python generator, so you `yield` values back and only `return` once the keyword occurs.

Comment: ahh that should work